# T-SQL - how can I use group by on xml objects

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've wrote the following query which I expect to return a data-set as outlined under the query

**Query**

```
SELECT 
RelatedRecordID AS [OrganisationID], 
Data.value('(//OpportunityViewEvent/Title)[1]','nvarchar(255)') AS OpportunityTitle,
Data.value('(//OpportunityViewEvent/ID)[1]','int') AS OpportunityID,
Count(Data.value('(//OpportunityViewEvent/ID)[1]','int')) AS Visits
FROM [Audit].[EventData]
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employed.Organisation AS ORG ON [EventData].RelatedRecordID = ORG.ID
Where EventTypeID = 4
Group BY RelatedRecordID
Order By Visits Desc
```

**Expected Result**

```
+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+--------+
| OrganisationID  | OpportunityTitle | OpportunityID | Visits |  
+-----------------+------------------+---------------+--------+
|              23 | Plumber          |           122 |    567 |  
|              65 | Accountant       |            34 |    288 | 
|              12 | Developer        |            81 |    100 | 
|              45 | Driver           |            22 |     96 | 
+-----------------+------------------+---------------+--------+
```

I receive an error saying

> Column 'Audit.EventData.Data' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

If I then try to group the xml data I get a different error saying

> XML methods are not allowed in a GROUP BY clause.

Is there a way to work around this?

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT` is processed after `GROUP BY`. If you want to group the results of select you should use a subquerey, eg `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... FROM EventData) x GROUP By ...`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll also give this way a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do by adding it into CTE

```
;with cte as (
SELECT 
 RelatedRecordID AS [OrganisationID], 
 Data.value('(//OpportunityViewEvent/Title)[1]','nvarchar(255)') AS   OpportunityTitle,
 Data.value('(//OpportunityViewEvent/ID)[1]','int') AS OpportunityID,
 Data.value('(//OpportunityViewEvent/ID)[1]','int') as visit
FROM [Audit].[EventData]
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employed.Organisation AS ORG ON [EventData].RelatedRecordID = ORG.ID
Where EventTypeID = 4 )
select OrganisationID, opportunityTitle, opportunityId,  count(visit) as Visits from cte 
Group BY OrganisationID, opportunityTitle, opportunityId
```